# Ring network Bernoulli with conversion rule

Tags: combinatorics, binomial-coefficients, network

Imagine there is a ring network $G$ with $N$ (odd) nodes. Nodes are initially $iid$, $a_i\overset{\text{iid}}\sim Ber(p)$. However, once the value is assigned, a node with $a_i=0$ will switch to $1$ if both of its neighbours are $1$. Define $f(G)=\sum_{i=1}^Na_i$ (total number of $1$'s in the network).

Then how can we express $P(f(G)\geq(N+1)/2)$  (majority of $1$'s) as a function of $N$ and $p$?

For example, if $N=3$ then $P(f(G)\geq2)=p^3+3p^2(1-p)$.

Without the conversion rule it would basically boil down to a Binomial distribution (which is now instead a lower bound) but the conversion messes up things.

Answer (score 1):

This probability will always be of the form:

$$a_{0} p^{0} (1 - p)^{N} + a_{1} p^{1} (1 - p)^{N - 1} + \dots + a_{N - 1} p^{N  -1} (1 - p)^{1} + a_{N} p^{N} (1 - p)^{0}$$
For a particular value of $N$ we can just go through all possibilities and compute them. I've tabulated all values below $16$ in the table below:

| N | 0 | 1 | 2 | 3 | 4 | 5 | 6 | 7 | 8 | 9 | 10 | 11 | 12 | 13 | 14 | 15 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 0 | 1 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 |
| 3 | 0 | 0 | 3 | 1 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 |
| 5 | 0 | 0 | 5 | 10 | 5 | 1 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 |
| 7 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 21 | 35 | 21 | 7 | 1 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 |
| 9 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 9 | 90 | 126 | 84 | 36 | 9 | 1 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 |
| 11 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 77 | 363 | 462 | 330 | 165 | 55 | 11 | 1 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 |
| 13 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 13 | 455 | 1443 | 1716 | 1287 | 715 | 286 | 78 | 13 | 1 | 0 | 0 |
| 15 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 195 | 2315 | 5670 | 6435 | 5005 | 3003 | 1365 | 455 | 105 | 15 | 1 |

Please notice that each of these rows has its second half in common with the Pascal's triangle (the lower bound you have observed). But we have the equality only for $N = 1$ and $N = 3$. The first half are half zeros and half some positive noise which I unfortunately cannot decipher (the fact that first $\frac{1}{4}$ is obvious though - the number of ones cannot double in this process).

Maybe you (or anyone else) can make sense of that. I was searching a bit on OEIS but haven't found anything of value.